# Free functions for stream manipulators vs overloading operator<< directly

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iomanip

I'm looking at possible designs for a custom stream class. Half an hour of searching on- and off-site have not led to an answer to my queries, so I'm asking a new question instead.

Take `std::endl` as an example. It is, if I am not mistaken, specified to work roughly like this (consider this to be "slide code"):

```
struct ostream
{
    using FManip = ostream& (*)(ostream&);
    ostream& operator<<(FManip f)
    {
        return f(*this);
    }
};

ostream& endl(ostream& s)
{
    /* ...do whatever... */
    return s;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6MP5cseas

However, it is unclear to me what the benefit of doing that is, as opposed to having tag objects and implementing `operator<<` directly for them:

```
struct ostream
{
};

// (reserved name - use whatever convention fits when writing library code)
struct _EndlManipTag {};
static constexpr _EndlManipTag endl;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, _EndlManipTag tag)
{
    /* ...do whatever... */
    return s;
}

int main()
{
  ostream os;
  os << endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dzj7v8fse

I understand that the first version is slightly less code to write for additional manipulators. That's not the worst reason, but it also seems more convoluted (how many people know that `std::endl` is actually a function), as well as straying further from the implementation of manipulators that have arguments (e.g. `std::setw(n)` returns an object that stores `n` and for which an appropriate `operator<<` overload exists - very close to the second snippet).

I wonder if there are any other considerations at play here (either at time of standardization or when looking at current C++ versions). Maybe subtleties in overload resolution? Compilation speed? Ease of optimization? Template friendliness? Error messages? Or is it simply of no relevance which approach I choose in new code?

Comment: For example `boolalpha` can be applied to istreams and ostreams, so you would have to overload `<<` and `>>` and probably end up with two wrappers that call the same function. Though thats also just a bit more to write

Comment: still only "more to write": because `boolaplpha` and others takes `ios_base&` as parameter it works with any stream that inherits from `ios_base`, but `std::istream` and `std::ostream` arent meant to be inherited from afaik. I'd love to see an answer from someone who knows what they are talking about. When I started I prefered your second approach, then I shifted to the idomatic, but I dont know why ;)